What should remote IP be in configuring port forwarding
My server is running locally on port 7000. I want to access it remotely using public IP. I want to create a port forwarding what will be the below fields should look like given in the picture.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

So you definitely need to set your "Local IP". it will be the LAN IP of the server on your network. For Remote address however, you want it to work for All remote IPs, so start off with it empty, and if it needs a value, try 0.0.0.0.

0.0.0.0 is not viable as router prompts it as invalid, leaving empty is not solving the issue

whats the make/model of your router? does anything change if you select the WAN interface in the Interface dropdown? you do have the Local IP set correct? have you checked to see if your firewall is allowing the traffic?
